# Will breaking out the context calls cause multiple trips to the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm refactoring some previously written MVC and Entity Framework code. The way the initial code was written they called a DAL.GetGroupDetail(int groupId) method. In that method it created a ViewModel and populated several properties. Some of those properties are Lists for things like CostCenters, Cities, Groups. I want to break those calls out into their own methods so that they can be re-used in other controllers.

My question is that doing that I'm creating new Contexts using the Using statement. My understanding is that would create multiple connections to the database and thus would slow down the site if multiple users were using it at the same time?

Example, currently this is the basic code:

```
public ClockGroupViewModel GetClockGroupDetail(int groupId)
{
    GroupViewModel cgdv = new GroupViewModel();

    using (var ctx = new VTContext())
    {
        bio_group group = ctx.bio_group.Where(x => x.group_id == groupId).FirstOrDefault();
        cgdv.GroupId = group.group_id;
        cgdv.GroupName = group.group_name;
        cgdv.Cities = ctx.bio_city.ToList();
        var clocks = from c in ctx.bio_clock.Where(x => x.group_id == groupId)
                     select new ClockViewModel
                     {
                         ClockID = c.rdr_id.ToString(),
                         ClockDescription = c.clock_desc,
                     };
        cgdv.ClockList = clocks.ToList();
        cgdv.CostCtrList = (from g in ctx.bio_clock_group
                            from cgc in ctx.bio_clock_group_costctr
                            where cgc.group_id == g.group_id && g.group_id == groupId
                            select cgc.cost_ctr).ToList();
    }
```

This how I'm thinking of changing it:

```
public ClockGroupViewModel GetClockGroupDetail(int groupId)
{
    GroupViewModel cgdv = new GroupViewModel();

    using (var ctx = new VTContext())
    {
        bio_group group = ctx.bio_group.Where(x => x.group_id == groupId).FirstOrDefault();
        cgdv.GroupId = group.group_id;
        cgdv.GroupName = group.group_name;
        cgdv.Cities = GetCityList();
        cgdv.ClockList = GetClockGroupClockList(group.group_id);
        cgdv.CostCtrList = GetGroupCostCenter(group.group_id);
    }
}

public List<bio_clock_city> GetCityList()
{
    using (var ctx = new VTContext())
    {
        return ctx.bio_city.ToList();
    }
}

public List<ClockViewModel> GetClockGroupClockList(int groupId)
{
    using (var ctx = new VTContext())
    {
        var data = (from c in ctx.bio_clock.Where(x => x.group_id == groupId)
                   select new ClockViewModel
                   {
                       ClockID = c.rdr_id.ToString(),
                       ClockDescription = c.clock_desc,
                   }).ToList();

        return data;
    }
}

public List<string> GetGroupCostCenter(int groupId) 
{
    using (var ctx = new VTContext())
    {
        var data = (from g in ctx.bio_clock_group
                    from cgc in ctx.bio_clock_group_costctr
                    where cgc.group_id == g.group_id && g.group_id == groupId
                    select cgc.cost_ctr).ToList();

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you are instaniating the DbContext in every method call.  Why not pass it in to the constructor of your class and have the same DbContext available to all of the calls.

Comment: I've been trying to play around with doing that. I created a context at the top of my class and then I just use using(ctx){ db code } instead of creating a new context in in each method. However, I get an error saying the context has already been disposed, which makes sense with using the using statement. So then the thought is to not use the using statement but then where to do you close and dispose of the context?

Comment: if you pull the DbContext instantiation out of the method and up to the class level you are going to have to remove those using() {} statements from the methods.  using ensures that objects are cleaned up and you don't want that.  you should implement dispose at the class level and dispose of the context there.